# i am executing this query in sql server 2008 r2 the result is " Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted" Please help me

Tags: sql-server-2008

```
 select purchase_id ,

 (case when (select source_type from dbo.tbl_Purchase where purchase_id  = tbl_Purchase.purchase_id)=1 then 

 (select vessel_name from dbo.tbl_Vessel where vessel_type=1)
 when  (select source_type from dbo.tbl_Purchase where purchase_id  = tbl_Purchase.purchase_id)=2 then 
 (select vessel_name from dbo.tbl_Vessel where vessel_type=2)
 else
 (select jetty_name from dbo.tbl_Jetty )

 end ) as vessl_name
 from tbl_Purchase
```

Comment: When you execute this `(some subquery) = 1` the subquery must return only one value, or the comparison can't proceed. One of your subqueries is returning more than one. What you do about it depends on the root cause of the problem. Do you have a duplicate where you shouldn't, perhaps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I *think* you just want something like this:

```
 select purchase_id ,
        COALESCE(v.vessel_name,j.jetty_name) as vessl_name
 from dbo.tbl_Purchase p
         left join
      dbo.tbl_Vessel v
         on
            p.source_type in (1,2) and
            v.vessel_type = p.source_type
         left join
      dbo.tbl_Jetty j
         on
            p.source_type not in (1,2)
```

Otherwise, if you're wanting to continue down your `CASE`/subquery path, you need to fix these statements:

```
(select source_type from dbo.tbl_Purchase where purchase_id  = tbl_Purchase.purchase_id)
```

where both sides of that comparison are in fact referencing the *same* table and the *same* column, and so it will always return *all* rows from `tbl_Purchase` (except those with a `NULL` `purchase_id`)

See the query above for how to use aliases (`p`, `v`, `j`) on tables so that you can specify which the correct source table is for each column reference. I.e. I'd expect something like:

```
(select source_type from dbo.tbl_Purchase p2 where p2.purchase_id  = p1.purchase_id)
```

Assuming that the original `tbl_Purchase` in the outer `FROM` clause has been given the alias `p1`.

---

Further reading:

[`COALESCE`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190349.aspx), [Using Joins](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191472%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

You have to remove last subquery from the main query and use join instead of 
subquery .